# How to copy down formula in Excel to last cell with data in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that will perform a formula and then place the value in Column G and then sort column G... The code works fine but I will be having a dynamically changed amount of row I need the formula to be ran for so I am trying to figure out how to change the range from just certain cells to all cells that have a value. Any help is appreciated. The code I have written is below.

```
Sub Sorting()
Worksheets.Select ("FedEx Air Ops Workbench Report")
Range("G4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],BUTTONS!R2C11:R6C12,2,FALSE)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G4:G58"), Type:=xlFillDefault
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FedEx Air Ops Workbench Report").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("G4:G58"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FedEx Air Ops Workbench Report").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A4:G58")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Rather than fish for you; consider this process using a macro recorder.  It may help with other problems later! step 1) Start macro recorder.  Step 2) place focus in column containing desired data. Step 3) press ctrl-down (assuming PC) on column which has desired values.  Step 4 stop macro recorder.  Step 5) review what system recorded so you know how the system can dynamically select the last cell.  (Ctrl-down will set focus to the last cell with data (Assuming no gaps in column)  ctrl-shift-end will give you all data on a sheet regardless of gaps.  Add shift to the key combo to select!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = WorkSheets("FedEx Air Ops Workbench Report")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print lastRow
ws.Range("G4").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],BUTTONS!R2C11:R6C12,2,FALSE)"
ws.Range("G4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("G4:G" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Does the above work?

Comment: When I do this its giving me an Run Time Error

Comment: It says method "range" of object_global failed

Comment: Just noticed something. `Worksheets.Select ("FedEx Air Ops Workbench Report")` should be `Worksheets("FedEx Air Ops Workbench Report").select`? What does `debug.print lastRow` say?

Comment: Its giving me the number 4.. I put it in the immediate window and pressed enter is that what you were saying?

Comment: Now I'm getting a run time error 1004 autofill method of range class failed

Comment: Huh. It works for me.... Edit: add a `ws.` before `Range("G4:G" & lastRow)`. If still fails, then I don't know :/

Comment: Ok now its running but its just not finding the last row for some reason its stopping at the 4th row and the debug.print lastrow is returning the number 4 and I dont understand why

Comment: Oh so G is blank to begin with. What's the column that G corresponds to? Edit: whatever that column is, just change the line for `lastrow` to that column.

Comment: What do you mean corresponds to? Column G is where I want the formula to populate but it is blank should I use the column next to it to get to the bottom?

Comment: Try changing the G to E.

Comment: Nevermind I got it now you were correct I put the wrong column thank you for that!